# NPM Module triggering a "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ..."! How do I fix it?

Tags: node.js, npm

My app was working just a short while ago until I merged the master branch. Then all of a sudden I started to get the following errors:

```
> @COMPANY/MY_APP@1.0.5 storybook /Users/THINKBONOBO/Workspace/MY_APP
> start-storybook -p 9001 -c .storybook

/Users/THINKBONOBO/Workspace/MY_APP/node_modules/generate-page-webpack-plugin/index.js:39
              ...acc,
              ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/THINKBONOBO/Workspace/MY_APP/node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/config/webpack.config.prod.js:18:57)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @COMPANY/MY_APP@1.0.5 storybook: `start-storybook -p 9999 -c .storybook`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @COMPANY/MY_APP@1.0.5 storybook script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

The error is from some imported public package and it seems it's written in ES6 and all of a sudden my app can't read it.

I tried clearing the cache, node_modules folder, restarting my computer, cloning to a different folder... All to no avail.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

The way I fixed this issue was that I updated my node version.

I was running 8.1.1 and updated it with brew (I originally installed node using brew)

`brew update ; brew upgrade node`

it upgraded to node v 10.10.0 and I was all set.

here's an article on how to update node js on a mac:

https://bytearcher.com/articles/ways-to-get-the-latest-node.js-version-on-a-mac/